# How to use momentjs npm-package in an angular2-meteor application?

Tags: meteor, momentjs, angular2-meteor

I want to use moment.js library in my angular2-meteor application. For this, I installed the npm package with:

`meteor npm install moment --save`

Now, in the component, where I want to use this library, I have to import it somehow:

`import {???} from 'moment';`

But what must be imported here, so I can use it somewhere in the component in the following way:

`var foo = moment().format('LLLL');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have used moment in one of my angular2-meteor app. for using moment.js you should import it like this

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

and delcare it and use it like this.

```
current_year_header: any;
date: any;
this.date = moment();
this.current_year_header = this.date.format('YYYY');
```